# How to Book Tickets When Kids Return With Different Person

Tags: air-travel, bookings, children

This summer our kids are going to visit grandparents for couple months. The itinerary looks like following:

- kids fly with their mother from Canada to Europe;
- their mother returns back to Canada alone;
- kids fly back to Canada from Europe with their aunt after couple months.

What is the best way to book air tickets without buying three sets of non-return tickets but still making sure kids will be on the same flight as their chaperon?

Is there a website which allows booking for such cases?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No regular website offers such customized demands. That's what travel agents specialize in. Your situation is however nothing you can't do yourself in 5 minutes. Book the kids tickets (with return coinciding with the Aunt's return date, you have to know that in advance), then book their moms tickets with the same departure day as the kids and her own return date. If you don't have dates in mind you will have to book open tickets which will cost you up to 2 times or more the cost of regular return tickets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, don't over complicate it.

Just book it exactly as you describe it.  All you need to do is be 100% sure the kids are book on the same flights as the adults.

Now for the complicated part ;)

Make reservations only first, meaning don't pay.  You will have to then call the airline and ask them how best to handle this to a) make sure the kids can fly if they are minors, b) avoid any Unaccompanied Minor fee, c) ensure you are seated together.

Mostly likely, they will just link the reservations and make whatever notations are necessary but, every airline has their own rules, procedures and nomenclature.

Be prepare to pay for pre-assigned seats.  And keep in mind, maybe not all airlines can accommodate this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain you will know of this but just to be sure: have a notarized letter stating the circumstances of your kids' travel. Include which parent and what Aunt will be traveling with your kids and have both you and your wife sign in front of a notary.

Comment: This does not provide a direct answer to the OP's question "How to make such a custom booking." This is better off as a comment.